# Buffer local mappings in Vim: <buffer> vs. <localleader>

Tags: vim

One thing interests me. If one were want to map a mapping specific to some buffer, one can go either way
a) do it with

```
nnoremap <buffer> d dd
```

b) or with

```
nnoremap <localleader>d dd
```

which will effectively, because localleader is specific to that buffer, make that mapping specific to that buffer too.

That in a way, seems like two overlapping ways to do one same thing. Is there a reason for using one way instead of the other? Is one way preffered over the other for some reason maybe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I can tell `maplocalleader` is shared between buffers.  This means that your second map would not be specific to a buffer.

Really, if you're defining a map that is specific to a buffer (e.g. the map only pertains to a specific filetype) I believe convention is to use both `<buffer>` and `<localleader>`.  If you're defining a map that is not specific to a buffer you should just use `<leader>`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So <localleader> is not buffer specific, but its intention is to be used for mappings that ARE buffer specific. I re-read the help now, and they couldn't put it more confusingly. Or have I gotten it wrong again?

Comment: Yes, you understand it as I do.  The `maplocalleader` is barely documented at all it seems, but after a bit of testing this seems to be the correct behavior.

Answer (score 3):

## 1 `<buffer>`

This is important to stop your mapping for a specific filetype becoming global having just once opened that filetype.

## 2 `<LocalLeader>`

This applies globally. As [described by R2A2](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/bkfaff/comment/emg92p7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), you can map `<LocalLeader>` to be a handy alternative to `<Leader>`. Somewhere in your `vimrc`:

```
let maplocalleader = '_'
nnoremap <localleader>h :echo 'you just hit _h'<cr>
```

You could use `<localleader>` with `<buffer>`, as recommended in Vim's internal help, for your ftplugin's, then it `_h` would only work in that filetype.